# Is it ok to build a simple page with dynamic content in Gatsbyjs?

Tags: seo

I have a page in React that shows different cards that are built using info from an API, like so:

[image]

Now I want to migrate it to gatsby, I've learned that I can use gatsby-source-rest-API.

Is it ok if I build this card-like page into Gatsby? aren't I breaking "the rules" of static site generation here?

I'm confused, and I'm new to Gatsby, but I think I need it in order to build SEO compliant pages

I also can use Next, but I think that it's overkill in my case.

And there's also apollo-client, but I'd like to try it without the use of more libraries

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never heard of rules for static site generation that prevent its use for card like pages.  Why do you think there might be such rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby supports [client-side rendering](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/), [server-side rendering](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/rendering-options/server-side-rendering/) and [static site generation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/).

You are totally free to choose the rendering strategy according to your data source. **Just like NextJS**.

If you want to generate static pages, the API used by Gatsby is very powerful and gives you more flexibility than NextJS. I'll make a quick example:

> You need to generate three static pages like `/slug-one`, `/slug-two`
> and `/slug-three`. Let's suppose those slugs come from a CMS and they
> are defined outside Gatsby and not controlled by you (the developer). Each page must be generated using a
> different React component (template).

With [Gatsby Node API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/) you can do that very easily. Dynamic pages are generated in a dedicated file named `gatsby-node.js`. You can basically tell Gatsby to generate each page using a different component file (template) e.g. `ComponentA.jsx` and to use the `slug` returned from a specific GraphQL field or any other API call to **build the path**. It doesn't matter if the path is the same, you can always use different templates.

https://yoursite.com/slug-one — Generated using `ComponentA.jsx`
https://yoursite.com/slug-two — Generated using `ComponentB.jsx`
https://yoursite.com/slug-three — Generated using `ComponentC.jsx`

With NextJS is practically impossible to generate dynamic pages in the **same path** using **different components**. This is because the logic to generate dynamic pages is written directly inside the component/page file.

From NextJS official docs:

> Defining routes by using predefined paths is not always enough for
> complex applications. In Next.js you can add brackets to a page
> ([param]) to create a dynamic route (a.k.a. url slugs, pretty urls,
> and others).
>
> Consider the following page pages/post/[pid].js:
>
> Any route like /post/1, /post/abc, etc. will be matched by
> pages/post/[pid].js. The matched path parameter will be sent as a
> query parameter to the page, and it will be merged with the other
> query parameters.

I guess this is the reason why Gatsby is best suitable for SSG.

Regarding your question, you can fetch data on build time (SSR and SSG) or on runtime (for example using useEffect after first render). Of course, you can fetch data on runtime also on a statically generated page.

If you decide to go with SSR or to fetch data after first render, you will have to use the APIs you always used like axios, graphql-request, apollo... Just like you would do with NextJS or CRA.

If you decide to go with SSG you most likely will have to use one of those plugins with the prefix `gatsby-source-***`.

**Those plugins do always the same job: they create nodes and expose your data to the [Gatsby GraphQL API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/graphql-api/).**

In short, Gatsby forces you to use its internal GraphQL API to fetch data coming from external sources when you need to SSG such data.

Bottom line, if your cards data changes very often, you can SSG the page containing the cards and then once the page is rendered fetch the cards with useEffect or SSR the entire page.

If your cards data doesn't change very often, pick the `gatsby-source` plugin according to the source and fetch the card data on build time.